# Are there any .IR registration restrictions for the US?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

Are there any restrictions on buying a `.ir` (IRAN) domain from the US? 
Would I be violating any laws?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ir):

> Generally open for Iranians and non-Iranians; 3rd-level registrations under subdomains have varied restrictions and are restricted to Iranian-related entities

There are no law preventing the registration of foreign TLDs including those assigned to Iran.